# Bad function call when using a std::function as a comparator

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I'm using lambdas instead of a comparator class for my set, but I'm running into issues.

I have something like this:

```
class Processor {
    
private:
    const function<bool(std::string, std::string)> _lenComp = [](string a, string b) { return a != b && a.size() >= b.size(); };
    set<string, decltype(_lenComp)> _inputSet;

// ...
    
public:
    Processor() : _inputSet() {
    }

    void addLine(string line) {
        _inputSet.insert(line);
    }
```

When I create a `Processor` instance and call `addLine` 2 times I get a bad function call exception.
How do I properly initialize this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`decltype(_lenComp)` is `function<bool(std::string, std::string)>` which is an empty `std::function`, so you get bad call when calling it.

what you wanted was the type of the lambda stored in it, you should define that with `static constexpr auto`, because you are not allowed to know the type of the lambda.

```
class Processor {
    
private:
    static constexpr auto _lenComp = [](string a, string b) { return a != b && a.size() >= b.size(); };
    set<string, decltype(_lenComp)> _inputSet;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the other answer: in this line the type of the lambda and the type of `_lenComp` are not the same:

```
const function<bool(std::string, std::string)> _lenComp = [](string a, string b) { return a != b && a.size() >= b.size(); };
```

`std::function<bool(string, string)>` is a generic wrapper functor that can hold any kind of function that returns a bool and takes two strings, be it a lambda, or a regular function, or a static method.  You can reassign the actual implementation that this container wraps.

What you have done is created a lambda which has an opaque (hidden) type and stored it in an instance of the wrapper.  Then you passed the type of the *wrapper* into the `std::set` template.

When `_inputSet` is constructed it has no knowledge of your lambda.  It will construct a new instance of the comparator type it was given, which in your case is an `std::function`.  And a default-constructed `std::function` is empty.

Another fix for the above if you wanted to keep `std::function` would be to pass the instance of the comparator that you already have to the set when it is constructed, like this:

```
// ...

    const function<bool(std::string, std::string)> _lenComp = [](string a, string b) { return a != b && a.size() >= b.size(); };
    set<string, decltype(_lenComp)> _inputSet;

public:
    Processor(): _inputSet({}, _lenComp) {}

// ...
```